# How to send changing input to a python script that asks for input in a while loop using a bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a python script that asks at the beginning for user to enter a password, simply like this:

```
password = input()
```

in my bash script I have:

```
echo -n "password: "
read -s password
printf "$password" | python my_script.py
```

this works fine but I have a condition that if user enters the password incorrectly, the script prompts him to type the password again until he types the correct one, something like this:

```
while not login:
    password = input()
    login = check_correct(password)
```

I should be able to handle this in my bash script but I'm not sure how, I tried using `yes` command like this:

```
yes $(read -s password) | python3 my_script.py
```

but this always sends, as expected, the same input to the script.
Does anyone have any idea how could I do this?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the script prompts for something else? How is the shell supposed to know when to stop sending passwords? And, why don't you use `expect` instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
while True:
    resp = input('Enter your password')
    if check_correct(resp):
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid Password, please try again')
```

Comment: If you are going to down votre my answer, at least have the courtesy of providing an explanation of why